# How can I load incrementally migrate data from PostgresSQL to HDFS?

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I have a postgresql database that I use for a production server. I want to set up an Hadoop/Spark cluster to run mapreduce jobs. In order to do that I need to load the data from my postgres database to hdfs. The naive approach is to have a batch job that once a day dumps the contents of the database (120GB) to HDFS. That would be wasteful and costly. Since most the data won't change from one day to the next, it could theoretically be much cheaper and more efficient to send just the diffs every day. Is this possible?

I've read a little about sqoop, and it seems to provide the functionality I want, but it requires making changes to the database and the application. Is there a way that doesn't require making any changes to the database?

Comment: You can't get incremental changes out of PostgreSQL prior to version 9.4 without adding triggers to record changes. In PostgreSQL 9.4 this will be possible using [logical decoding](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/logicaldecoding.html), but you'd have to write the code that gets the logical decoding change stream and adapts it for consumption by Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

- Apache Sqoop can connect to postgreSQL database.

  Sqoop provides an incremental import mode which can be used to retrieve only rows newer than some previously-imported set of rows, i.e, you can get the table updates happened between previous run and current run.
- No changes are required to database.

Using Sqoop postgreSQL connector you can connect Sqoop to your database and get the incremental imports without any database changes.

Comment: according to the sqoop documentation here: http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports I need to have a column in every table indicating whether it was modified or not. I don't have that. Is there a way for sqoop to detect this automatically, similar to how slave databases get updated?